# How to share context when is depending of request in graphql module and Dynamoose Module?

Tags: module, graphql, request, nest, dynamoose

I have this configuration with GraphQL and Dynamoose modules, the graphql module is using the follo context:

```
context: ({req}: { req: Request }) => ({req}),
```

However this context in not shared with Dynamoose revolvers, is marked as undefined, but if the context is shared as object is possible to use, but I need the graphql context based on requests:

```
context: {
  user: 'jose'
},
```

But in the final implementation the request are not shared.

References:
https://github.com/hardyscc/nestjs-dynamoose

https://github.com/hardyscc/aws-nestjs-starter

```
@Query(/* istanbul ignore next */ () => [Notification])
  notificationByTargetId(
    @Args('targetId') targetId: string,
    @Context('user') user,
  ) {
       console.log('findByTargetId')

    return this.notificationService.findByTargetId(targetId, user);
  }
```

```
import { NotificationModule } from './modules/notification/notification.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloDriver,
      autoSchemaFile: true,
      playground: true,
      context: ({req}: { req: Request }) => ({req}),
    }),
    DynamooseModule.forRoot({
      local: process.env.IS_DDB_LOCAL === 'true',
      aws: { region: process.env.REGION },
      table: {
        create: process.env.IS_DDB_LOCAL === 'true',
        prefix: `${process.env.SERVICE}-${process.env.STAGE}-`,
        suffix: '-table',
      },
    }),
    NotificationModule,
    DefaultFilterConfigurationModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```